# How do I make a button show the listbox when clicked?

Tags: c#, buttonclick

I am making a form where if a button is clicked it will go to my list box and run the functions I have in there though I am a bit confused on how to make it realise when the button has been clicked and for the listbox to work. Here is my code >_>

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

public void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ping.PlayConsole();
}
```

Comment: you want the listbox to show when the button is pressed ?

Comment: Yes, I want to make it so that when the button is clicked it goes to the listbox and then run the method which is inside it, aka "Ping.PLayconsole();"

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ping.PlayConsole();
}
```

It's ok to call the same function under different handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender,e);
}
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: I get "no overload for method takes 0 arguments" how would I go about fixing this? :/

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox.Focus();
    Ping.PlayConsole();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both event handlers share the same  signature `void (object , EventArgs)`, so they are call-compatible.

*If you are connecting the event visually using the form designer:*

Go to the Property Inspector's Events pane and instead of double-clicking it to create an event handler stub for `button1.Click`, click the dropdown box icon that appears on the right side.  Visual Studio will show all the event handlers present in the form that have a compatible signature, you should be able to choose `ListBox_SelectIndexChanged` for the `button1.Click` handler. They will be sharing the same handler.

*If you are connecting the handler by code then this should work too:*

```
ListBox1.SelectIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
```